# Understanding HoldSequence and ReleaseHoldSequence in Error Handling

Tags: warning-messages, undocumented

I was playing with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` in V10.1, and find some of native Mathematica functions using `` Macros`HoldSequence `` and `` Macros`ReleaseHoldSequence `` in some sort of error handling.

Someone knows why this is used? How it works?

Here is the `DeleteDuplicatesBy` code structure.

```
Self:DeleteDuplicatesBy[expr_,f_]:=Module[{r$},

  r$=Which[
     !Quiet[TrueQ[!AtomQ[expr]||AssociationQ[expr]||Head[expr]===SparseArray]]
     ,Message[DeleteDuplicatesBy::normal,1,HoldForm[Self]];$FailRHS
    ,True
    ,HoldSequence[
        Which[
        ListQ[expr]
            ,Values[GroupBy[expr,f,First]]
        ,AssociationQ[expr]
            , Association[Values[GroupBy[Normal[expr],f@*Last,First]]]
        ,Head[expr]===SparseArray
            ,DeleteDuplicates[expr,f[#1]===f[#2]&]
        ,True
            ,expr[[Values[GroupBy[Table[{f[expr[[i]]],i},{i,Length[expr]}],First,First]][[All,2]]]]
        ]
      ]
    ];

  ReleaseHoldSequence[r$]/;!MatchQ[r$,$FailRHS|HoldSequence[$FailRHS]]

]
```

Comment: Well, this is just a way to process errors. Since `Which` is evaluated right away, the fact that it reached tha part wrapped in `HoldSequence` means that there are no errors in the input. The `$FailRHS` symbol is used to separate the error - reporting logic (issue messages etc) at the top from the actual decision for the rule to match or not match, at the bottom. There are many ways to do this, this is just one of them.